# Emgu CV memory leaks on loading more than 1000 training images

Tags: c#, emgucv

i just dont know what to do within this method LoadFaceRecognition, 
this method load the training images smoothly when it have less than 800 training images but as soon as I add  images the loading of data stops executing and memory consumption expands. Please help me with this

training imgaes are the Grayscale images

this is LoadFaceRecognition,

```
private bool LoadFaceRecognition(string Training_Folder, string TrainedFaces) { 

  if (File.Exists(Training_Folder + TrainedFaces + "/TrainedLabels.xml"))
    {
        try
        {
            Names_List_Faces.Clear();
            trainingImages_Faces.Clear();
            FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(Training_Folder + TrainedFaces + "/TrainedLabels.xml");

            long filelength = filestream.Length;
            byte[] xmlBytes = new byte[filelength];
            filestream.Read(xmlBytes, 0, (int)filelength);
            filestream.Close();

            MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes);
            XmlReader xmlreader = XmlTextReader.Create(xmlStream);

            while (xmlreader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlreader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (xmlreader.Name)
                    {
                        case "NAME":
                            if (xmlreader.Read())
                            {
                                //Names_List_ID.Add(Names_List.Count); //0, 1, 2, 3....
                                Names_List_Faces.Add(xmlreader.Value.Trim());
                                NumLabels_Faces += 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case "FILE":
                            if (xmlreader.Read())
                            {
                                //PROBLEM HERE IF TRAININGG MOVED
                                trainingImages_Faces.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Training_Folder + "/TrainedFaces//" + xmlreader.Value.Trim()));

                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ContTrain_Faces = NumLabels_Faces;
            if (trainingImages_Faces.ToArray().Length != 0)
            {
                recognizer_Faces = new EORecognizer(trainingImages_Faces.ToArray(), Names_List_Faces.ToArray(), Eigen_Threshold, ref termCrit_Faces);
                return true;

            }
            else return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few Dispose or using statements there.

You need to free up resources for some of the objects you are using like the Strems.

Try with the following code:

```
private bool LoadFaceRecognition(string Training_Folder, string TrainedFaces) { 

      if (File.Exists(Training_Folder + TrainedFaces + "/TrainedLabels.xml"))
        {
            try
            {
                Names_List_Faces.Clear();
                trainingImages_Faces.Clear();
                using (FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(Training_Folder + TrainedFaces + "/TrainedLabels.xml"))
                {

                    long filelength = filestream.Length;
                    byte[] xmlBytes = new byte[filelength];
                    filestream.Read(xmlBytes, 0, (int)filelength);
                    filestream.Close();

                    using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
                    {
                        using(XmlReader xmlreader = XmlTextReader.Create(xmlStream))
                        {

                            while (xmlreader.Read())
                            {
                                if (xmlreader.IsStartElement())
                                {
                                    switch (xmlreader.Name)
                                    {
                                        case "NAME":
                                            if (xmlreader.Read())
                                            {
                                                //Names_List_ID.Add(Names_List.Count); //0, 1, 2, 3....
                                                Names_List_Faces.Add(xmlreader.Value.Trim());
                                                NumLabels_Faces += 1;
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        case "FILE":
                                            if (xmlreader.Read())
                                            {
                                                //PROBLEM HERE IF TRAININGG MOVED
                                                trainingImages_Faces.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Training_Folder + "/TrainedFaces//" + xmlreader.Value.Trim()));

                                            }
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ContTrain_Faces = NumLabels_Faces;
                            if (trainingImages_Faces.ToArray().Length != 0)
                            {
                                recognizer_Faces = new EORecognizer(trainingImages_Faces.ToArray(), Names_List_Faces.ToArray(), Eigen_Threshold, ref termCrit_Faces);
                                return true;

                            }
                            else return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: actually I already tried that code but nothing change. still the loading of training images takes too much time and  of memory and worst the program cannot load faster